# How would I manage 2 different builds for 2 different stores, which requires a little bit of a code change between them

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say I want to publish my game on both Steam and Epic Games. Both have an SDK with certain services like matchmaking.

I don't want to make 2 projects and basically maintain both of them just to be able to achieve this. How do I activate/deactivate certain code depending on which version I'm building (the Steam one, or the Epic Games one). I read about #if directives, but those seem to work only when checking build target platform (Android, etc).

- Can I make use of these directives to achieve my goal?
- Can I include both sdks and check via code if it's the Steam or the Epic version and initialize the correct one accordingly some way?.

Comment: Thats why conditional defines are made. You define your own and do #if client1 …. Etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add and define your own preprocessor directives `#if STEAM` or `#if EPIC`.

```
#if STEAM
  //do something with STEAM API
#elif EPIC
  //do something with EPIC API
#endif
```

To do this you need to open "Project Settings->Player->Script Compilation->Scirpting Define Symbols" and there you can find a list of all custom preprocessor directives that Unity will use to compile your project.

If you wish to do the same during build process automatically you can set [PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup.html)

```
PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup
(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, "STEAM");
```

Fore more information see this [PlatformDependentCompilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

You can do the same thing for all plugins and DLL you want to include in your project via [Define Constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PluginImporter.DefineConstraints.html)